# Add dynamic variables to login_path and check_path

Tags: symfony

In my case, when a user login our system, we have to figure out what source he/she is from. We have to add a dynamic variable to login_path, failure_path.

I searched a lot but did't find a useful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to help others, I list what I found for my question.

1. no need to add variables to path of firewall, it supports route name
   with variables, symfony will get all veriables from url path ,and fill them into all routes of firewall.
2. add global variables to all routes .
   There is a example in symfony that demostrates how to add extra global variables to all routes. checkout this class `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create two classes and then reference them as the handler services in your `security.yml`.

First off, take a look at `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler`. These are the classes that are called when authentication succeeds or fails and are passed the relevant options from your `security.yml` configuration.

Create your own classes and extend from these defaults, overriding the `onAuthenticationSuccess` and `onAuthenticationFailure` methods with your own business logic (i.e. your dynamic variables). Then set them up as services:

```
my.authentication.success_handler:
    class: My\Authentication\SuccessHandler
    arguments: [ "1", "2", "3" ]

my.authentication.failure_handler:
    class: My\Authentication\FailureHandler
    arguments: [ "4", "5", "6" ]
```

Then in security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        my_firewall:
            form_login:
                success_handler: my.authentication.success_handler
                failure_handler: my.authentication.failure_handler
```

Then when you log, the relevant `onAuthenticationX` method will be called. You probably want to return a redirect response like in the defaults but with your dynamic variables added on.

If you want an easy way of maintaining / retrieving the options from the default handlers, I'd suggest looking into [Service Decoration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services) from the Symfony Cookbook.

Comment: Thanks, John,I find a better way without creating new class, I find out that both login_path, check_path just simply support route name , if variable exist in these route name, the firewall somewhere will get variables from path, and fill it into check_path.